# Custom login page per subaccount in Canvas LMS?

Tags: authentication, customization, canvas-lms

I have a hosted Instructure Canvas LMS instance. I've created several sub-accounts like hr-training, dev-training, support-training, and so on.

I'd like each of the these sub-accounts to have their own, custom login pages - the UI elements on these UI pages would change from one sub-account to another. Elements like the login page background color, department name, and elements like that need to be different for each of the departments.

Is this possible?

Could I, for example, have pages and URLs like hr-training.mycompany.com, dev-training.mycompany.com, support-training.mycompany.com, and so on? Each of these pages would have the same login elements (username/password), but different look-and-feel, and when the students submit their usernames/passwords, it takes them to their specific sub-account in Canvas LMS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge that is not a thing.  The canvas login page isn't tied to the sub accounts and while you can inject style (CSS) to customize the canvas page, I don't know of a way to split the styling of that based on DNS name.

Additionally, you couldn't change the behavior of the login itself it is just going to take the person to their dashboard, regardless of the DNS name they used when hitting the login.

Comment: I saw this comment in the Canvas LMS community forums, and hoped that someone had taken it to the next level:
https://community.canvaslms.com/thread/13143-login-page-for-sub-accounts